# How should I reconnect this switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I suppose it's a three-way. The red light it's the only hot wire. It was like that when I came to the house. But the wire on top of the red it's going to other room switch and light. The one next to it. It's going to the room light. And the one under it's going to the other switch same room. I don't know where the other one is going.

It's in a room with two entrances. One light. And no the other room switch and light are not working.

[image]

I found this too. But idk if it was from there.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: How was it connected?  what was in that box?  Are you in the USA?

Comment: Was like that when I came to the house.  But the wire on top of the red it's going to other room switch and light. The one next to it. It's going to the room light.  And the one under it's going to the other switch same room.  The other one idk where is going

Comment: So do those other switches not work right now?  It's common for a hot wire to pass through one box to get to some others.  What should this switch control?  A room with two entrances or a hallway could have a 3-way switch.  If it's a light in one room with one door, a three way isn't likely.

Comment: Room with two entrance. One light. And no the other room switch and light are not working

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to keep track of your comments; would you edit the info (and more) into your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: So Red to White is your hot?  I wonder if it's (or was) actually a 4-way.

Comment: Which ones look like they were once bent around screws (J-hooks), and which ones look like they were on wire-nuts (angled scratches and spiral twists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my idea, but please post a picture of the other switch of that room.
[image]